# pybind11: AttributeError: module 'XXX' has no attribute 'YYY' when trying to run function from py file

Tags: python, c++, pybind11

I am trying to launch function z from file test.py from the same folder, where executable is located:

```
def z(k):
    return 9.
```

and the calling code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <pybind11/embed.h>
namespace py = pybind11;
using namespace std;
int main(){
    py::scoped_interpreter guard{};
    auto module = py::module::import("test");
    auto resultobj = module.attr("z")(9);
    py::function z =
            py::reinterpret_borrow<py::function>(
                    py::module::import("test").attr("z")
            );
    py::object resulto = z(1);
    double result = resulto.cast<double>();
    cout << result<<endl;
    return 0;
}
```

it crashes like this:

```
terminate called after throwing an instance of 'pybind11::error_already_set'
  what():  AttributeError: module 'test' has no attribute 'z'
```

Module test is clearly loaded, because if I replace test with test1 in C++, then program crashes in a different way. Also if I replace test and z with math and sqrt, it also works. How do I fix my problem?

Comment: make sure you have `z` in `test.py`. `python -c "import test; print(test.z(9), test.z(1));"`

Comment: did that already, it works

Answer (score 0):

My first hypothesis is that another module named `test` is being loaded first (shadowing your `test.py`). You can verify the full path of the module by adding

```cpp
    py::print(module.attr("__file__"));
```

If this is the case, you can also rename `test.py` to a less common name.

I compiled your code and the output is as expected.